# Oracle SQL - Define table names for later usage?

Tags: sql, oracle, tablename

I wanted to know if there is a way, in SQL Oracle, to do some range-definition (like in Excel). For example:

**DEFINE TABLE1 =** SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 FROM [SCHEMA].[TABLE0][WHERE/GROUP BY/HAVING/ORDER BY/...];

**DEFINE TABLE2 =** SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 FROM **TABLE1** [WHERE/GROUP BY/HAVING/ORDER BY/...];

**DEFINE TABLE3 =** SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 FROM **TABLE2** LEFT JOIN **TABLE1** ON [CONDITIONS];

SELECT * FROM TABLE3;

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you considered common table expressions (the WITH clause)?

Comment: @Steve, I only understand the following logic: "WITH TABLE1 AS [Table Structure], TABLE2 AS [Table Structure] SELECT * FROM TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2;" & that's it. I'm not sure if there is a more complex logic behind this clause though...

Comment: It's a bit difficult to give a meaningful example with only the abstract data you posted, but a with-clause can contain any kind of select query (including the use of group-by and where clauses). The logic can be as complex as you need it to be - you can also chain the table references, so the contents of one CTE can refer to an earlier one (i.e. TABLE2 could select from or join onto TABLE1, in your example, with both being defined inside the with-clause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO close this question. From one of the comments (Steve), what I needed is a WITH clause, as I didn't have DDL privileges.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Based on your examples, it sounds like you want to [create views](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504):

```
CREATE VIEW TABLE1 AS
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3
FROM [SCHEMA].[TABLE0][WHERE/GROUP BY/HAVING/...];

CREATE VIEW TABLE2 AS
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3
FROM TABLE1 [WHERE/GROUP BY/HAVING/...];

CREATE VIEW TABLE3 AS
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3
FROM TABLE2
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 ON [CONDITIONS];

SELECT * FROM TABLE3;
```

Comment: but you would not (I hope) actually call a view table1, table2  or table3. It is more usual to name views so that you know they are view; e.g. TABLE0_V1, TABLE0_V2, TABLE0_V3 and NEVER include ORDER BY in  view definition

Comment: @Used: ...same as I wouldn't call a table that either. But to your point, I know it's common to see views prefixed or suffixed in some way to identify them as such. Personally, I think there is no need for that. But I absolutely agree that you wouldn't want an ORDER BY in the view definition. Edited.

Comment: glad we agree on not using order by in views. The naming convention IMHO is important too, especially for those unfamiliar with the data model, however debates on naming conventions are usually unproductive :)

Comment: @Used_By_Already - why "NEVER include ORDER BY in view definition"? What is wrong with that?

Comment: Apparently, it is irrelevant (according to AskTom, here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9533711800346372460) because (quoting) "before a query is optimized, it goes through a phase called "transformation" where we (Oracle) look for ways of re-writing the query which would potentially give more options for optimization *without* changing the intent of the SQL". So, if optimizer finds out that view's ORDER BY isn't used (or overrided by SELECTs own ORDER BY), query is transformed and ORDER BY is left out.

Comment: I think the important thing is not to start view names with `'TABLE'` ;)

Comment: @littlefoot despite the potential for the optimizer to ignore an unused order by, all too often the optimizer just doesn't do that and the cost of the irrelevant order by is seen in explain plans. There simply is no good reson to define an order by in a view. Ordering should be left to the final query only.

Comment: Hi @sstan, thanks a lot, this may be helpful. || Only one question: do you know any other way that can only be done with "SELECT" privileges? The database I want to revise is a Production Schema, so I don't have any other capability than view.

Comment: If you only have the `SELECT` privilege, then the best you can do is use the `WITH` clause, which is similar to defining a view, but can only be reused within that same query where the `WITH` clause is defined.